# How can I determine whether a CUDA context is the primary one - cheaply?

Tags: cuda, cuda-context, cuda-driver

You can (?) determine whether a CUDA context is the primary one by calling [`cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html#group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX) and comparing the returned pointer to the context you have. But - what if nobody's created the primary context yet? Is there a cheaper way to obtain the negative answer then? Or - is it impossible for a non-primary context to exist while the primary does not?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the primary context has been created ("activated") or not:

```
inline bool primary_context_is_active(int device_id)
{
    unsigned flags;
    int is_active;
    CUresult status = cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState(device_id, &flags, &is_active);
    if (status != CUDA_SUCCESS) { /* error handling here */ }
    return is_active;
}
```

Now, if the primary context is *not* active, then you know your context is not the primary one; if it *is* active, you can use `cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain()`, and - unless you're doing something multi-threaded or using coroutines etc. - you know it'll be a cheap call.

This of course depends on assuming your context is not an invalid primary context handle after disactivation.

Comment: @talonmies: Oh, yes, you're right, it's the primary context.

Comment: If there is a preceding `cudaSetDevice(idx)` call, this approach won't work reliably for CUDA 11 and below that uses lazy context initialization: `cudaSetDevice(idx)` still places the context on the top of the stack, and the state query gives `active == 0`.

Comment: @biubiuty: Well, if you actually hold a context, and it's the primary one, then - context creation has already occurred IIANM. Otherwise - how would you have the context handle?

Comment: `cudaSetDevice(idx)` then `cuCtxPopCurrent(&ctx)` gives a valid primary context in `ctx`. Following a call to `cuCtxPushCurrent(ctx)`, the `cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState()` will give `active == 0` because although the primary context is created, it has not been initialized.

Comment: @biubiuty: Hmm. Need to do some experimentation now... thanks.